# Bouncing ball animation working but top y value not changing in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on an animation in Jetpack Compose where an emoji needs to bounce but with each bounce, its top y value needs to decrease, however all I am getting is a regular bouncing animation, as shown below:

[image: bouncing emoji]

Hence I used **repeatable** where the **top y** value of the emoji needs to change with each iteration.

But when I tried to set the **animationSpec** to a variable **topDp**, then it's always taking the initial value & hence I am getting the same animation as shown in above picture, when what I want is decreasing top Y value with every iteration..

Code is as follows:

```
@Preview
    @Composable
    fun BouncingEmoji() {
        var topDp by remember {mutableStateOf(0.dp)}
        var emoState by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
        val offsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
            targetValue = if (emoState == 0) topDp else 150.dp,
            animationSpec = repeatable(
                iterations = 5,
                animation = tween( durationMillis = 400,
                    easing = FastOutLinearInEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse), label = "r1"
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = Color.Gray)
        )  {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.emo1),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(60.dp)
                    .absoluteOffset(y = offsetAnimation)
            )
        }
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            emoState = 1
            topDp = 75.dp
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring animationSpec this might help you just replace the below snippet

**Preview**
[image: preview]

```
val offsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (emoState == 0) topDp else 150.dp,
        animationSpec = spring(
            dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy,
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow,
        ), label = "r1"
    )
```

Comment: Appreciate this solution but I cannot customize the damping beyond 3 values(high/medium/low). Plus I want to apply an additional step animation along X axis. Will I be able to approach these problem, with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative should be animating to floor position then up again with reduced distance from max distance each step and lowering each up down bounce time as

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun BouncingEmoji() {
    var topDp by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    var emoState by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val step = 4

    val offsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = topDp,
        animationSpec = tween(
            // change speed of each bounce to match distance traveled
            durationMillis = 400 / (1 + emoState / 2),
            easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
        ),
        label = "r1",
        finishedListener = {

            emoState++

            topDp = if (emoState < step * 2 + 1) {
                if (emoState % 2 == 0) {
                    // This is where you change how high it will go after hitting floor
                    // refining this function will have smoother distance changes
                    // while bouncing up
                    150.dp - (150.dp / (1 + emoState / 2))
                } else {
                    150.dp
                }
            } else {
                150.dp
            }
        }
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.Gray)
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
    ) {

        Text(

            text = "",
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .absoluteOffset(y = offsetAnimation)
        )

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            delay(2000)
            emoState = 1
            topDp = 150.dp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! This is very near to what I wanted.